# Cocos2d equivalent jump action in SpriteKit iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I could not find Cocos2d jumpBy or jumpTo equivalent in apple's latest SpriteKit framework.
Can somebody tell me how to create an exact jump action in SpriteKit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one here to help ?

Comment: What have you tried?  No one is likely to just give you the answer since it creates work for that person.  The API's are similar perhaps you can make an extension to SpriteKit taking the code for JumpBy and JumpTo and integrating it with SpriteKit.  I haven't used SpriteKit so I don't know all the hooks an ways to extend that are available.

Comment: Well, in Cocos2d, we have jumpTo and jumpBy actions. But in SpriteKit, we don't have these actions.

I have tried an algorithm for jump like this:
http://babek.info/libertybasicfiles/lbnews/nl126/parabolicnally.htm

But it does not produce the effect I want. 
I want "Flappy Bird" like jumping effect.

Comment: Sure the actions aren't available in SpriteKit but Cocos2D is open source so I'm suggesting to take that code and integrate it with SpriteKit or make a custom extension to it or make a custom extension just for the project you need it for.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the direction. I will try that now. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Let me know how it turns out.